# Edit comment template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have poked around the web and Visual Studio file structure and I am getting the feeling that it isn't possible, however I was wondering if anyone knew how to edit the code comment templates for C# in VS 2010.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

I was able to change the class file template so it would seem like the ability it there to do it manually, but I have no idea where MS would stick the file.

Any insight would be great,
patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400027) you can create an xml template file and Visual Studio will use it instead of the built-in template.  However, [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/b5127511-9c68-40e8-a884-756b2adddbf0) and many others suggest that this feature is specific to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting that feeling but wanted to try anyway. I made the file and no such luck, even tried a couple variations. Oh well, hopefully MS will add this functionality to the Studio.